# cvSaveImage was not declared in this scope OpenCV3.4

Tags: c++, opencv

My teacher provide me  source code of a project which is maybe based on *OpenCV 2 or 3*.

I tried to run it, but I get an error: ‘cvSaveImage’ was not declared in this scope. Like this:

```
root@qrh-pc:/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/build# make
Scanning dependencies of target TREFFIC_SIGN_QT_PROJECT
[  3%] Building CXX object bin/CMakeFiles/TREFFIC_SIGN_QT_PROJECT.dir/Camera.cpp.o
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp: In member function ‘void CCamera::renderImage()’:
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp:380:5: error: ‘cvSaveImage’ was not declared in this scope
     cvSaveImage(imageSaveFileName.c_str(), img);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp:380:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘cvShowImage’
     cvSaveImage(imageSaveFileName.c_str(), img);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
     cvShowImage
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp: In member function ‘void CCamera::renderImage(CameraParams, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBL>::Ptr, pcl::PointIndices&)’:
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp:511:5: error: ‘cvSaveImage’ was not declared in this scope
     cvSaveImage(imageSaveFileName.c_str(), img);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp:511:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘cvShowImage’
     cvSaveImage(imageSaveFileName.c_str(), img);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
     cvShowImage
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp: In member function ‘void CCamera::renderImageCalOccludeCloud(CameraParams, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBL>::Ptr, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBL>::Ptr)’:
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp:659:5: error: ‘cvSaveImage’ was not declared in this scope
     cvSaveImage(imageSaveFileName.c_str(), img);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/TrafficSignBlockCalProject/src/Camera.cpp:659:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘cvShowImage’
     cvSaveImage(imageSaveFileName.c_str(), img);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
     cvShowImage
bin/CMakeFiles/TREFFIC_SIGN_QT_PROJECT.dir/build.make:81: recipe for target 'bin/CMakeFiles/TREFFIC_SIGN_QT_PROJECT.dir/Camera.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/CMakeFiles/TREFFIC_SIGN_QT_PROJECT.dir/Camera.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:133: recipe for target 'bin/CMakeFiles/TREFFIC_SIGN_QT_PROJECT.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [bin/CMakeFiles/TREFFIC_SIGN_QT_PROJECT.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@qrh-pc:/home/qrh/文档/TrafficSignQtProgram/build#
```

OpenVC 3.4 is my version, I tried to include many head fies, but it doesn't work.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to add your code and edit the question. And try to be more clear to explain your question. You may visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cvSaveImage` is supported by **openCV2**. The supported alternative method in **openCV3** and **openCV4** is `imwrite` method. For further info check this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce)

```
C++:
bool cv::imwrite    (   const String &  filename,
InputArray  img,
const std::vector< int > &  params = std::vector< int >() 
)       
Python:
retval  =   cv.imwrite( filename, img[, params] )
```

Comment: You're right. I uninstalled opencv4. But when I try to compile opencv3. X, I get an error/home/qrh/下载/opencv3/modules/stitching/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/matchers.hpp:52:12: fatal error: opencv2/xfeatures2d/cuda.hpp: 没有那个文件或目录
 #  include "opencv2/xfeatures2d/cuda.hpp"